# jQuery plugin for connecting / linking two elements ( by user )

Tags: javascript, jquery, connection, html5-canvas

I have two sets of elements and user is supposed to connect elements from first set with elements in the second set with a line - like this:

[image: dragging options]

I am looking for a jQuery or pure JS plugin, which can do this - also I need it to have some callback that will "tell" me that the connection was succesful and which elements have been connected. It would also be nice to be able to disable the connect lines. (So user could correct his answer).

Thanks for any future help and tips!

Comment: what is wrong with this question ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this jquery plugin - jsPlumb:
http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/home/jquery.html

Comment: Looks promising :) Demo - Drag&Drop could be my solution - any tips how to customize the drag&drop little boxes ? :)

Comment: i suggest using chrome browser, right click on a little box > inspect element, then in the right css pane, play a little bit with the css parameters and see if you can learn from that. that's what i'm used to. good luck!

Comment: Well I ment some practical tip :) - I recommend others to look through the "demo-jquery.js" a demo jsPlumb file and see the exampleEndpoints - their properties and where they are used :)

Comment: No longer works. Check out this and update the answer please: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Connect-Two-Html-Elements-with-A-Line/